# Upload documents to existing envelope draft DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I have been using the api to upload documents to DocuSign. Each time it creates a new Envelope Draft. We need to be able to use the api to upload documents to an existing Envelope Draft.

Comment: Your question is not really clear and thus people will not  be able to help you. Please describe what you have tried so far, what code (if any) have you written, what is the exact error you are getting and/or where are you getting stuck. Describing all these things will make it much more likely to get useful answers. I also suggest you to read this link for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

When you POST to /envelopes DocuSign creates a new envelope.  As you've found, setting status to "created" will create a draft envelope.  To modify an existing envelope you must use the PUT method instead of POST.